# Specify path to ZeroClipboard.swf, Laravel + jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4, zeroclipboard

I'm creating a functionality to copy text from textarea to clipboard. I'm using [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/) jquery plugin, based on Zero Clipboard. I have Laravel 4 project, and I have ZeroClipboard.swf in 'public/js/ZeroClipboard.swf', and trying to add copy to clipboard functionality in view file, which is in 'app/views'. I have this code:

```
$('#copy_btn').zclip({
  path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
  copy:$('#textarea').text()
});
```

Browser console sais that `GET http://mysite.dev/sites/1/ZeroClipboard.swf 404 (Not Found)`. The URL 'http://mysite.dev/sites/1/' is a route to view file i'm loading, and there is no ZeroClipboard.swf file there, it is just route. And thats why 'ZeroClipboard.swf' is not found. So how to specify correct path in the code above?

Comment: Change  path:'ZeroClipboard.swf', to  path:'../../js/ZeroClipboard.swf',

Comment: @MattBurrow I tried that, but the error in console is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
ZeroClipboard.config( { swfPath: "http://YOURSERVER/path/ZeroClipboard.swf" } );
```

As Documented [here](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use php code in your views, I think the best option is to use the asset manager,
like **link_to_asset** [(more here)](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls)
or to use like

```
URL::asset('css/foo.css', $secure);
```

Hope this will help you to make it more laravel-way.